# Magento 2.2.4 - Adding 'Declared Value' to UPS Shipping Calculations

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.2.4, ups, setup-di-compile

It appears the UPS integration inside Magento 2 does not include the declared value when calculating shipping quotes which can drastically make the quotes way off.

Anyone else experience this and find a way to have this included?

**EDIT:**

I found this module: https://github.com/xantek/magento2-ups-declared-value

However when DI Compiling, I receive this error;

```
Xantek\UpsDeclaredValue\Model\Carrier
Incompatible argument type: Required type: 
\Magento\Framework\HTTP\ClientFactory. Actual type: array; File:
/app/code/Xantek/UpsDeclaredValue/Model/Carrier.php

Total Errors Count: 1


[Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception]
Error during compilation
```

Comment: I think that the contractor of the Model is out of date with your Magento version

Comment: @HoangHieu Is there any simple solution to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your used newest Magento version than the Module.

**Magento 2.2.4 Ups Carrier Model __construct**

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Security $xmlSecurity,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\ElementFactory $xmlElFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory $trackFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\ErrorFactory $trackErrorFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $trackStatusFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        Config $configHelper,
        ClientFactory $httpClientFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
```

Change the module constructor like this code

**Xantek\UpsDeclaredValue\Model\Carrier**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    Security $xmlSecurity,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\ElementFactory $xmlElFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory $trackFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\ErrorFactory $trackErrorFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $trackStatusFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    Config $configHelper,  
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ClientFactory $httpClientFactory, 
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct(
        $scopeConfig,
        $rateErrorFactory,
        $logger,
        $xmlSecurity,
        $xmlElFactory,
        $rateFactory,
        $rateMethodFactory,
        $trackFactory,
        $trackErrorFactory,
        $trackStatusFactory,
        $regionFactory,
        $countryFactory,
        $currencyFactory,
        $directoryData,
        $stockRegistry,
        $localeFormat,
        $configHelper,
        $httpClientFactory,
        $data
    );
}
```

Or just use auto-generation of IDE to generate the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I got another error now when trying to compile: 
 [ReflectionException]
  Class Xantek\UpsDeclaredValue\Model\Magento\Framework\HTTP\ClientFactory does not exist -- [RuntimeException]
  Source class "\Xantek\UpsDeclaredValue\Model\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client" for "Xantek\UpsDeclaredValue\Model\Magento\Framework
  \HTTP\ClientFactory" generation does not exist.

Comment: Updated answer, I missed the "\"

Comment: Thank you, everything works perfectly now!